# Graph API mobileApp Install Summary alternative

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I used the InstallSummary methods in the beta API before, but they were deprecated in May 2023. What other ways are there to get the same data? Is it possible to use another API?
[doc1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLTno.png)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-apps-mobileappinstallsummary?view=graph-rest-beta

I tried with deviceStatuses and userStatuses, but they were deprecated in May 2023 too.In version 1.0, these things are also missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stumbled on the same issue. After some investigations into how the Endpoint portal from MS receives this information, it seems to work by using the `/beta/deviceManagement/reports` endpoint. It seems to be a very dynamic endpoint, cause it will also return the structure of the objects within the `Values` collection and after some further search I found the following page:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/intune-customer-success/support-tip-retrieving-intune-apps-reporting-data-from-microsoft/ba-p/3851578

It contains a table about the deprecated calls and the new calls available:

- FailedAppCounts

  - /deviceManagement/mobileApps/getMobileAppCount(status={status})
  - /deviceManagement/reports/getFailedMobileAppsSummaryReport
- TopFailedMobileApps

  - /deviceManagement/mobileApps/getTopMobileApps(status={status}, count={count})
  - /deviceManagement/reports/getFailedMobileAppsReport
- AppInstallStatusAggregate

  - /deviceManagement/mobileApps/ with install summary expanded
  - /deviceManagement/reports/getAppsInstallSummaryReport
- AppStatusOverview

  - /deviceManagement/mobileApps({appId})/installSummary
  - /deviceManagement/reports/getAppStatusOverviewReport
- DeviceInstallStatusByApp

  - /deviceManagement/mobileApps({appId})/deviceStatuses
  - /deviceManagement/reports/getDeviceInstallStatusReport
- UserInstallStatusAggregateByApp

  - /deviceManagement/mobileApps({appId})/userStatuses
  - /deviceManagement/reports/getUserInstallStatusReport
- DependentAppsInstallStatus

  - /deviceManagement/mobileApps({appId})/getRelatedAppStates
  - /deviceManagement/reports/getRelatedAppsStatusReport

As it seems the Graph SDK is here also very hard to use, cause the endpoint just returns a stream, which must be deserialized on yourself. It also returns a schema of the data in the values property, but I don't think this is necessary if you request a specific endpoint and you can assume to always get the same schema back.

This is not a *full answer*, but when we got more insights on how to use this interface through the Graph SDK I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon the same issue today. In typical Microsoft fashion they removed it without providing an alternative. (I can't find it at least).

Apparently the guys from Patch My PC also struggle with this:

https://patchmypc.com/intuneapplicationmanagerstatistics

They say that they will use a different endpoint, but don't mention which one either.